# tablesorter.widgets causes conflict with jqueryUI for javascript validation on DOM elements in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom, tablesorter

This is how I include files:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="#request.base#/etc/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]><!-->
<script src="#request.base#/etc/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!-- Tablesorter: required -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#request.base#/css/theme.blue.css">
<script src="#request.base#/etc/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="#request.base#/etc/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="#request.base#/css/blitzer/1.9.2/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<script language="javascript" src="#request.base#/etc/jquery-ui-1.9.2.full.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="codes_scripts.js"></script>
```

On calling the ValidateAdd function (codes_scripts.js) from a form that resides inside 'tablesorter' table with this call==> onsubmit="return validateAdd(this); nothing happens in IE whereas it works fine in Chrome and Firefox. If I move the row containing this form, outside of tablesorter table, it starts to work. Ideas?

```
function validateAdd(formobj){
  with (formobj)
  {
    var alertMsg = ""; l_Msg = alertMsg.length;
    var strVal = document.getElementById("InsertFormUploadKey").value;

    //1) Enter name of mandatory fields
    var fieldRequired = Array("TheCode", "codename", "country", "IssuingAuthority", "IssuingAuthorityCode", "ReferenceURL");
    //2) Enter field description to appear in the dialog box
    var fieldDescription = Array("Code", "Code Name", "Country", "Issuing Authority", "IA Code", "Reference URL");

    //3) Enter dialog message
    var alertMsg = "Please provide/correct the following information:\r  \n";
    var l_Msg = alertMsg.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < fieldRequired.length; i++)
    {
        var obj = formobj.elements[fieldRequired[i]];
        if (obj){
            //alert("field: " + fieldDescription[i] );
            switch(obj.type){
            case "select-one":
                if (obj.selectedIndex == -1 || obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text == "" || obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text == "Select:" ||obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text == "Select" || obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text == "---"){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
                break;
            case "select-multiple":
                if (obj.selectedIndex == -1){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
                break;
            case "radio":
                //if (!(obj.checked == true))
                if (obj.checked != true)                
                {
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                if (obj.selectedIndex != -1) //(obj[0].checked!=1) && (obj[0].checked!=1) ){
                //it doesn't recgognize radios unless suffix is specified eg obj[i].type determines if its a radio -(!(obj.value))
                {
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
                break;
            case "text":
            case "textarea":
                if (obj.value == "" || obj.value == null || obj.value == "Unassigned"){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
                break;
            }//end switch
        }//end if
    }//end for

   //Decide the fate of form submission here
    if (alertMsg.length !== l_Msg)
    {
        alert(alertMsg);
        return false;
    }
    else{
         document.getElementById("InsertFormUploadKey").value = "1";
        return true;
    }
        //formobj.submit();     //document.designate.submit();
  }//end with(formobj)
}
```

HTML containing the form:

```
<table id="uploadTable" name="uploadTable" class="tablesorter<cfif getcodes.recordcount EQ 0> hidden</cfif>">
    <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Code Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Issuing Authority</th>
            <th>IA Code</th>
            <th>Reference URL</th>
            <th>Is Premium</th>
            <th>Is Listed</th>
            <th>Last Update</th>
            <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
     <tr>
        <form name="codeAdd" id="designate" method="post" action="codescrud.cfm" onsubmit="return validateAdd(this);">
            <td><p><input name="TheCode" maxlength=5 size=7 style="font-size:11px;"></p></td>
            <td><p><input name="codename" maxlength=50 size=40 style="font-size:11px;"></p></td>
            <td><p><select id="country" name="country">
                    <option value="Select_Country" selected>---</option>
                    <cfoutput query="getCountries">
                        <option value="#country#">#country#</option>
                    </cfoutput>
                </select></p>
            </td>
            <td><p><input name="IssuingAuthority" size=40 maxlength=200  style="font-size:11px;"></p></td>
            <td><p><input name="IssuingAuthorityCode" size=4 maxlength=50  style="font-size:11px;"></p></td>
            <td><p><input name="ReferenceURL" size=20 maxlength=255  style="font-size:11px;"></p></td>
            <td><p><input type="checkbox" name="IsPremium" class="cbx" id="IsPremium" title="Is Premium?" value="1"></p></td>
            <td><p><input type="checkbox" name="IsListed" class="cbx" id="IsListed" title="Is Listed?" value="1" checked></p></td>
            <cfoutput><input type="hidden" name="InsertFormUploadKey" id="InsertFormUploadKey" value="1"></cfoutput>
            <td colspan="3" align="right"><p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add New Code" class="button actionBtn" /></p>
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="uploadBody">
    <cfoutput query="getcodes">
        <tr class="uploadRow"><input name="code" value="#code#" type="hidden" class="uploadKey">
            <td valign="top"><p><span class="uploadCode">#code#</span></p></td>
            <td valign="top"><p><span class="uploadCodeName">#codename#</span></p></td>
            <td valign="top"><p><span class="uploadCountry">#country#</span></p></td>
            <td valign="top"><p><span class="uploadIssuingAuthority">#IssuingAuthority#</span></p></td>
            <td valign="top"><p><span class="uploadIssuingAuthorityCode">#IssuingAuthorityCode#</span></p></td>
            <td valign="top"><p><span class="uploadReferenceURL"><cfif ReferenceURL NEQ ""><a href="#ReferenceURL#" target="_blank">link</a></cfif></span><span style="display: none;" class="uploadReferenceURLValue">#ReferenceURL#</span></p></td>
            <td valign="top"><p><span class="uploadIsPremium"><cfif getcodes.IsPremium>True<cfelse>False</cfif></span></p></td>
            <td valign="top"><p><span class="uploadIsListed"><cfif getcodes.IsListed>True<cfelse>False</cfif></span></p></td>
            <td valign="top"><p>#DateFormat(lastupdate)#</p></td>
            <td valign="top"><p><button class="button actionBtn deleteUploadBtn" style="width:55px">delete</button></p></td>
            <td><p> <button class="button actionBtn editUploadBtn" style="width:55px">edit</button></p></td>
        </tr>
       </cfoutput>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: First off, you know [Microsoft dropped support for IE version less than 11](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support) in Jan 2016? So, if it doesn't work in IE8, IE9 or IE10, I wouldn't worry about it. Secondly, please share some HTML - like where is the form in relation to the table?

Comment: I'm using IE11 (though I added checks for IE less than 8, removing those lines of code has no effect). Below is the table, that shows the form being in the first row of the table: